# R ggplot set ymax but not ymin without cutting data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to set a ggplot's max y value while keeping the default min y but I need to use `coord_cartesian` as I want to zoom in, not exclude any data from calculations.

I'm surprised that I couldn't find the answer to this. There are many questions answering how to [expand limits to a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47949469/ggplot-set-ylim-min-or-max) or [set only one limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214012/set-only-lower-bound-of-a-limit-for-ggplot) using `scale_._..` but I can't find any using `coord_cartesian` to set only one limit

For example; using the example plot from `?coord_cartesian`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
```

I want the equivalent of

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 4))
```

without having to set 1.5 as the min.

If I could use `scale_y_continuous` I could use

```
p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA, 4))
```

but this limits all data contributing to my smooth to values less than 4 which I don't want, and the equivalent `p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(NA, 4))` returns an error.

Is there an easy replacement?

I could also come up with a calculation based on the data of the min of the plot, but this could become complicated if I am faceting the plot or similar.

Comment: This is an open issue on ggplot2's GH page ([link](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2907)), with a proposed fix for `ggplot2:::scale_range` that addresses the issue.

Comment: Ah, okay, I guess i'll just have to wait and use work-arounds for the present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in ggplot2 3.3.0 on 5-Mar-2020.

Now `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(NA, 4))` runs without errors.

**Example**

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(NA, 4))
```

Below is the description of the feature in the [NEWS file](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/625a03ad7d161b95f6b4b5c203d6d0a87ba19bc9/NEWS.md#ggplot2-330) (bullet 2 under 'New features').

> - All `coord_*()` functions with `xlim` and `ylim` arguments now accept   vectors with `NA` as a placeholder for the minimum or maximum value   (e.g., `ylim = c(0, NA)` would zoom the y-axis from 0 to the maximum value observed in the data). This mimics the behaviour   of the `limits` argument in continuous scale functions   (@paleolimbot, #2907).